# google homeのアプリをリリースした後、dialogflowでintentの編集は可能か？

Tags: google-cloud, google-api, dialogflow

google homeを使った自作アプリを作成しています。
アプリ作成後、googleへ申請、リリース（一般のグーグルホームから呼び出し可能な状態）を考えています。
dialogflowとの連携を行っていますが、リリース後にintentの内容を追加・削除は可能なのでしょうか？
それとも、編集したら変更を適用するために再度申請が必要なのでしょうか？

ご存知の方がいましたら、ご教示いただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

リリース後にintentの追加や削除をした場合は、変更を反映するために再申請が必要です。